# Radio connection - NRF2401A

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, modules

I am struggling to create the radio connection between RPi (rev 2.0, latest Raspbian Wheezy) and Atmega8A. I have modules based on NRF2401 ([TLX2401 datasheet](http://www.emod.com.pl/en/docs/TLX2401.pdf)).

The library on RPi side is [RF24](https://github.com/stanleyseow/RF24/tree/master/librf24-rpi/librf24), however it is written for NRF24L01. I use [this write-up](https://www.semiconductorstore.com/pdf/NewSite/nordic/WP_Interface_SPI_nRF2401.pdf) to maintain SPI interface.

After plenty of hours spent on trying to make it work, I am on the verge to give up. The result of `rpi-hub` example is listed below:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/RF24/librf24-rpi/librf24/examples# ./rpi-hub
SPI device       = /dev/spidev0.0
SPI speed        = 8000000
CE GPIO  = 4
STATUS           = 0x7f RX_DR=1 TX_DS=1 MAX_RT=1 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=1
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0x7f7f7f7f7f 0x7f7f7f7f7f
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f
TX_ADDR          = 0x7f7f7f7f7f
RX_PW_P0-6       = 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f 0x7f
EN_AA            = 0x7f
EN_RXADDR        = 0x7f
RF_CH            = 0x7f
RF_SETUP         = 0x7f
CONFIG           = 0x7f
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0x7f 0x7f
Data Rate        = 1MBPS
Model            = nRF24L01
CRC Length       = 16 bits
PA Power         = PA_MAX

Output below :
Recv: size=127 payload= pipe=7
Recv: size=127 payload= pipe=7
Recv: size=127 payload= pipe=7
(...)
```

The values are obviously invalid - it seems, that RPi does not communicate with Nordic module at all. Could anybody please help me out? How shall I port this library to my modules?